# How to set subwindow height dynamically in Vaadin

Tags: liferay, vaadin, liferay-6

I have a very strange problem in my vaadin application. I am opening a subwindow from main window and that subwindow performs some actions in background and display some new content the process continues to change the contents likewise.

The problem is each content is of different amount so the height of each should be set accordingly. How do I set height of windows? Auto-height isn't working.

PS: I am not using new windows each time instead the content is modified.

Edit: Also custom css like

`Height: auto; overflow: auto`

is not working.

Comment: you are saying, that the openend window keeps the size of the beginning and later changes to it do not effect the height any more?

Comment: Yes exactly. For simplicity say at first I display 100 lines and the sub-window gives scrollbar by default. Next content is of 10 lines so height should set accordingly which is happening. Again if next content is of 100 lines, then it doesn't display scroll-bar. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Window window = new Window("Window caption");                 
window.setResizable(false);                                   
window.setHeightUndefined();                                  


final VerticalLayout vl = new VerticalLayout();               
vl.setMargin(true);                                           
vl.setHeightUndefined();                                      
button = new Button("Add component");                         
button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {          
    public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {        
        vl.addComponent(new Label("Thank you for clicking")); 
    }                                                         
});                                                           
vl.addComponent(button);                                      
button = new Button("Remove component");                      
button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {          
    public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {        
        vl.removeComponent(vl.getComponent(2));               
    }                                                         
});                                                           
vl.addComponent(button);                                      
window.setContent(vl);
```

Important here is that height of window and layout is undefined.

Comment: I tried above but still there is same problem. Any other suggestion?